# Help identify this component

Tags: resistors

What is this component? It's between two ICs, probably on a communication bus. One is a microcontroller and the other is some sort of memory. It's as small as an smd capacitor or resistor.

[image: component written "220" on it]

Comment: What's the pin 1 indication for? They're symmetrical.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a (hand-soldered) quad **resistor array**. The resistors' value is indicated the same way it's done on single resistors: the first two digits for significant digits, and the third for the multiplier (power of 10). So `220` should be read as \$22 \times 10^0 = 22\Omega\$.

[image]

SMT resistor arrays exist in **dual, quad and octal** versions. They're often used on microcontroller buses, either in series with for example data lines, or as pull-ups for the address bus. Arrays are **space-saving** and **cheaper** than single parts. (Placing a part is several times more expensive than the cost of the part itself, so placing 1 array costs only 1/4 of placing 4 single resistors.) The quads are most often used, even for wider buses because they're easier to layout on complex boards. For the pull-ups there are **resistor networks** with one side of all resistors connected to a single pin.

[image]

Just like single resistors the arrays exist in different sizes, where the size is indicated in tens of mils (hundredths of inches). So a `0804` package is 80mils x 40mils (2mm x 1mm). **Convex** and **concave** pinouts exist.

[image: concave and convex resistor network]

There are also capacitor networks, as well as combined resistor-capacitor networks.
Manufacturers include Vishay, Yageo and Rohm.

Answer (score 9):

It's a quad 22.0 Ohm resistor........

Comment: tricky. I've never seen quad resistors before. tnx

Comment: They are used alot on motherboards in our computers. There are also octal ones.

Comment: Specifically, it's an isolated resistor array.  Some resistors that appear similar can be bussed to provide X (usually 9 or 15) pull-ups in a small space with a minimal number of vias.

Answer (score 1):

Resistor network. A chip that contains resistors in a latter or isolated configuration.